# Find if a table is mappable/contains an Obj column

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

How do I check whether a table is mappable?

I am trying to select all records from a table that contain objects, like this:

```
Select * From TableName Where Obj Into TempTable
```

If a table doesn't have an Obj column then this will cause an error. How can I check for the existance of the Obj column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TableInfo() function to query a table for a number of attributes, one is whether it is mappable.

Try:

```
If TableInfo(TableName, TAB_INFO_MAPPABLE) Then
   Select * From TableName Where Obj Into TempTable
End if
```